# Accessing application's documents from device through USB?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8, winprt

I'm working with a Windows Phone 8 application that writes logs to a file on the device. Is there a way to get access to that file? If not, what are my alternatives to seeing log information outside of using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can read the file from isolated storage as long as it's a developer app installed on a developer unlocked phone. I use [the Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to do this, and there is a command line tool that comes with the SDK itself as well called [IseTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! What's the name of the command line tool?

Comment: It's IseTool.exe - I've added a link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For your own access you can just use the advice in Paul's answer. If you want to get the files from other users you can use the [Email Task](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/1-how-to-perform-email-tasks-in-a-wp7-app) and attach the log file to the email and have it sent to you or use some [form of server logging](http://nlog-project.org/2011/01/09/nlog-for-windows-phone-7.html).

Comment: +1: bear in mind there's a 64K limit on the email task, and you can't use attachments.